# Select query returning only one result per product?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a MySQL database, where I have to tables. A product-table with unique product and a price-table that contains Several prices for each product.

Today I use the following query, that will return rows for as many different prices present in price-table for each product:

```
SELECT product.id as id, price.unit_price as price
FROM product 
   INNER JOIN price 
     ON price.product_id=product.id 
WHERE category_id = 234
```

How can I change this query to only return a single row for each product with the lowest price (price.unit_price) present in the price-table and is it possible with only a single query?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use MIN().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way:

```sql
SELECT product.id as id, min(price.unit_price) as price
FROM product 
   INNER JOIN price 
     ON price.product_id=product.id 
WHERE category_id = 234
group by product.id
```

Comment: Thanks .. Initial I missed the GROUP BY which only returns a single result, but now it seems to work very nice .. Thanks for the answer .. all of you.

Comment: Worth considering Gordon's answer as well; window functions can look a bit more complex but they're also more flexible. For example, if you added a third column later you'd need to add it to the group by or also aggregate it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses window functions:

```
SELECT p.id as id, pr.unit_price as price 
FROM product p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pr.product_id ORDER BY pr.unit_price DESC) as seqnum
      FROM price pr
     ) pr
     ON pr.product_id = p.id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE p.category_id = 234;
```

This allows you to bring in addition columns from either table.  Otherwise, just use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id as id, MIN(pr.unit_price) as price 
FROM product p INNER JOIN
     price pr
     ON pr.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.category_id = 234;
```